# picking and choosing variables to activate and a user input method to do so

Tags: java

I have 14 variables that I have defined, but only want these to apply to a logarithm I have developed when explicitly called on via User Input. The logarithm I've made is for a tabletop RPG group of mine for character creation and uses "elemental alignments" in order to influence statistical data. The most a person can use are 5 of these at any time but no less than one.

```
double elemFire
double elemIce
double elemWater
double elemWind
double elemEarth
double elemPoison
double elemGravity
double elemShadow
double elemLight
double elemElec
double elemHoly
double elemAnti
double elemVoid
double elemTime
```

How would I call these specific variables using user input and ensure that a minimum of one and a maximum of 5 can be used at any given time?

The logarithm for calculations is absolutely massive as is and I do not want to have to make 14 more copies of that massive block of code. The biggest ambition is to cause the 1-5 variables called on to add a cumulative effect to the core stats for easier display.

This is the logarithm.

```
Scanner sin = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("What year were you born? :");

      yearBorn = sin.nextDouble();
      logHPCalc = 2.0 / 16.0;
      yourHP = yearBorn * logHPCalc;
      yourMP = yourHP / 2.0;
      yourNP = yourMP / 3.0;
          yourPSI = yourNP + yourMP / 32.0;
            logATK = yearBorn / 60.0;
            logDEF = yearBorn / 120.0;
            logMAG = yearBorn / 60.0;
            logSPR = yearBorn / 120.0;
            logSPD = yearBorn / 60.0;
            logLCK = yearBorn / 120.0;
            logEATK = yearBorn / 60.0;
            logEDEF = yearBorn / 120.0;
                statATK = yourHP / 2.0 + logATK;
                statDEF = yourHP / 3.0 + logDEF;
                statSPR = yourMP / 2.0 + logSPR;
                statMAG = yourMP / 3.0 + logMAG;
                statSPD = yourNP / 2.0 + logSPD;
                statLCK = yourNP / 3.0 + logLCK;
                statEATK = yourPSI / 2.0 + logEATK;
                statEDEF = yourPSI / 3.0 + logEDEF;

      System.out.print("What year is it? :");

                yearNow = sin.nextDouble();
                logHPCalcNow = logHPCalc * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0;
                yourHPNow = yearBorn * logHPCalcNow;
            yourMPNow = yourHPNow / 2.0;
                yourNPNow = yourMPNow / 3.0;
                yourPSINow = yourMPNow + yourNPNow / 32.0;
                    logATKNow = yearBorn / 60.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0;
                    logDEFNow = yearBorn / 120.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0;
                    logMAGNow = yearBorn / 60.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0;
                    logSPRNow = yearBorn / 120.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0;
                    logSPDNow = yearBorn / 60.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0;
                    logLCKNow = yearBorn / 120.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0;
                    logEATKNow = yearBorn / 60.0 * yearNow * 2.0 * 32.0;
                    logEDEFNow = yearBorn / 120.0 * yearNow * 2.0 * 32.0;
                        statATKNow = yourHPNow / 2.0 + logATKNow;
                        statDEFNow = yourHPNow / 3.0 + logDEFNow;
                        statSPRNow = yourMPNow / 2.0 + logSPRNow;
                        statMAGNow = yourMPNow / 3.0 + logMAGNow;
                        statSPDNow = yourNPNow / 2.0 + logSPDNow;
                        statLCKNow = yourNPNow / 3.0 + logLCKNow;
                        statEATKNow = yourPSINow / 200.0 + logEATKNow;
                        statEDEFNow = yourPSINow / 300.0 + logEDEFNow;

        nonHPBase    = 200;
        nonATKBase   = 5;
        nonDEFBase   = 5;
        nonSPDBase   = 4;
        nonLCKBase   = 2;
        nonHPGain    = nonHPBase * nonDEFBase - 10 + yearNow;
        nonATKGain   = nonHPBase * nonATKBase / 25 + yearNow / 200;
        nonDEFGain   = nonHPBase * nonATKGain / 110 + yearNow / 200;
        nonATKDEFSum = nonATKGain + nonDEFGain;
        nonSPDGain   = nonHPBase * nonATKDEFSum / 1000 + yearNow / 200;
        nonSPDSum    = nonHPBase * nonATKDEFSum / 2000;
        nonLCKGain   = nonHPBase * nonSPDSum / 400 + yearNow / 200;


usrTRANS = 4;

        transHP = yearBorn * logHPCalc * usrTRANS;
    transMP = yourHP / 2.0 * usrTRANS;
    transNP = yourMP / 3.0 * usrTRANS;
        transPSI = yourNP + yourMP / 32.0 * usrTRANS;
            translogATK = yearBorn / 60.0 * usrTRANS;
            translogDEF = yearBorn / 120.0 * usrTRANS;
            translogMAG = yearBorn / 60.0 * usrTRANS;
            translogSPR = yearBorn / 120.0 * usrTRANS;
            translogSPD = yearBorn / 60.0 * usrTRANS;
            translogLCK = yearBorn / 120.0 * usrTRANS;
            translogEATK = yearBorn / 60.0 * usrTRANS;
            translogEDEF = yearBorn / 120.0 * usrTRANS;
                transstatATK = yourHP / 2.0 + logATK * usrTRANS;
                transstatDEF = yourHP / 3.0 + logDEF * usrTRANS;
                transstatSPR = yourMP / 2.0 + logSPR * usrTRANS;
                transstatMAG = yourMP / 3.0 + logMAG * usrTRANS;
                transstatSPD = yourNP / 2.0 + logSPD * usrTRANS;
                transstatLCK = yourNP / 3.0 + logLCK * usrTRANS;
                transstatEATK = yourPSI / 2.0 + logEATK * usrTRANS;
                transstatEDEF = yourPSI / 3.0 + logEDEF * usrTRANS;
                translogHPCalcNow = logHPCalc * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0 * usrTRANS;
                transHPNow = yearBorn * logHPCalcNow * usrTRANS;
            transMPNow = yourHPNow / 2.0 * usrTRANS;
                transNPNow = yourMPNow / 3.0 * usrTRANS;
                transPSINow = yourMPNow + yourNPNow / 32.0 * usrTRANS;
                    translogATKNow = yearBorn / 60.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0 * usrTRANS;
                    translogDEFNow = yearBorn / 120.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0 * usrTRANS;
                    translogMAGNow = yearBorn / 60.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0 * usrTRANS;
                    translogSPRNow = yearBorn / 120.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0 * usrTRANS;
                    translogSPDNow = yearBorn / 60.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0 * usrTRANS;
                    translogLCKNow = yearBorn / 120.0 * yearNow + 2.0 * 32.0 * usrTRANS;
                    translogEATKNow = yearBorn / 60.0 * yearNow * 2.0 * 32.0 * usrTRANS;
                    translogEDEFNow = yearBorn / 120.0 * yearNow * 2.0 * 32.0 * usrTRANS;
                        transstatATKNow = yourHPNow / 2.0 + logATKNow * usrTRANS;
                        transstatDEFNow = yourHPNow / 3.0 + logDEFNow * usrTRANS;
                        transstatSPRNow = yourMPNow / 2.0 + logSPRNow * usrTRANS;
                        transstatMAGNow = yourMPNow / 3.0 + logMAGNow * usrTRANS;
                        transstatSPDNow = yourNPNow / 2.0 + logSPDNow * usrTRANS;
                        transstatLCKNow = yourNPNow / 3.0 + logLCKNow * usrTRANS;
                        transstatEATKNow = yourPSINow / 200.0 + logEATKNow * usrTRANS;
                        transstatEDEFNow = yourPSINow / 300.0 + logEDEFNow * usrTRANS;
```

I want these 14 variables to affect this, but only when called on, and only a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 5. Code optimization help is optional but would be GREATLY appreciated.

==============EDIT FOR A COMMENT=============

now uhh, Randy? It doesn't like doing math.
This is how the element variables are set up:

```
elemFire     = 10 * 2 * 2 / 32
elemIce      = 10 * 2 * 3 / 32
elemWater    = 10 * 2 * 4 / 32
elemWind     = 10 * 2 * 5 / 32
elemEarth    = 10 * 2 * 6 / 32
elemPoison   = 10 * 2 * 7 / 32
elemGravity  = 10 * 2 * 8 / 32
elemShadow   = 10 * 2 * 9 / 32
elemLight    = 10 * 2 * 10 / 32
elemElec     = 10 * 2 * 11 / 32
elemHoly     = 10 * 2 * 12 / 32
elemAnti     = 10 * 2 * 13 / 32
elemVoid     = 10 * 2 * 14 / 32
elemTime     = 10 * 2 * 15 / 32
```

I need this thing to be able to do math. otherwise if i can wrap my head around your "add things to the map" instructions and the

```
for (String element : elements) {
yourHp += elementMap.get(element);
```

thingamajig it'll be perfect if i can inject this into my big-arsed class.

---------------EDIT 7/15 ---------------------

Rob, what.. exactly is the ultimate output variable in that code you wrote out, because either I'm not understanding which one it is or i can't find it.

I'm going to pastebin my code with what you wrote inside it. It is commented. It won't run, because i either do not know where the ultimate output variable is in your element selection array is, or it simply does not exist.

where I have TRIED to put it to make it work is clearly marked.

http://pastebin.com/SFVRbs08

apologies for tab lacking, due to pastebin.

Comment: That's "algorithm", not "logarithm"

Comment: Sorry for the bluntness, but that is surely some of the ugliest code I've seen, and by ugly, I sense that there is a lot of redundant code that can be simplified greatly by use of methods and possibly arrays or collections. Doing this will make debugging and upgrading much easier as well.

Comment: what part of "newbie" don't you get?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (runnable example)

```
// Import our collections (Maps and Lists)
import java.util.*;

public class Elements {
    // Instead of having 14 separate variables, you can store your
    // "element effects" in a Map, using the element name as a key.
    private static Map<String, Integer> elementMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    static {
        elementMap.put("fire", 10 * 2 * 2 / 32);
        elementMap.put("ice", 10 * 2 * 3 / 32);
        elementMap.put("water", 10 * 2 * 4 / 32);
        elementMap.put("wind", 10 * 2 * 5 / 32);
        elementMap.put("earth", 10 * 2 * 6 / 32);
        elementMap.put("poison", 10 * 2 * 7 / 32);
        elementMap.put("gravity", 10 * 2 * 8 / 32);
        elementMap.put("shadow", 10 * 2 * 9 / 32);
        elementMap.put("light", 10 * 2 * 10 / 32);
        elementMap.put("elec", 10 * 2 * 11 / 32);
        elementMap.put("holy", 10 * 2 * 12 / 32);
        elementMap.put("anti", 10 * 2 * 13 / 32);
        elementMap.put("void", 10 * 2 * 14 / 32);
        elementMap.put("time", 10 * 2 * 15 / 32);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> elementValues = getElementValues();
        double yourHp = 1234.0;
        System.out.println("Starting HP: " + yourHp);
        for (Integer elementValue : elementValues) {
            yourHp += elementValue;
        }
        System.out.println("Ending HP: " + yourHp);
    }

    private static List<Integer> getElementValues() {
        // Your input scanner:
        Scanner sin = new Scanner(System.in);
        // This list will keep track of all the elements entered by the user
        List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Ask for up to 5 elements
        while (elements.size() < 5) {
            System.out.println("Select up to 5 elements ('q' to finish selecting) [" + elements.size() + " selected so far]: ");
            // Get what the user entered (they have to hit "Enter" before it gets read)
            String element = sin.next();
            if (element.trim().equals("q")) {
                if (elements.size() == 0) {
                    // If the user asked to quit but hasn't selected any elements,
                    // prompt them again
                    System.out.println("You must select at least one element:");
                } else {
                    // If they want to quit and have selected at least one, then
                    // break out of the while loop and keep going.
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                // They didn't ask to quit, so maybe they entered an element
                if (elementMap.get(element) == null) {
                    // If elementMap.get() returns null, then it's not a valid element
                    System.out.println("Not a valid element, try again:");
                } else {
                    // They entered a good element, so store it
                    elements.add(element.toLowerCase());
                }
            }
        }
        // Now there are between 1 and 5 elements stored in the elements list,
        // and we just have to get their values that are stored in the map.
        List<Integer> elementValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String element : elements) {
            elementValues.add(elementMap.get(element));
        }
        return elementValues;
    }
}
```

(P.S. It's "[algorithm](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3aalgorithm)", not "[logarithm](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3alogarithm)"--they're anagrams, but very different things.)

Comment: err, could you comment that so i know what does what? also, it only seems to calculate only for fire and water, not all 14. D:
also, how would i combine this into my main class? I'ma  relative newbie to java and i'm doing this as an exercise in variables so i get comfy with them. I don't know how to import things yet.

Comment: Commented. Have another look. Try running it and typing "fire" at the prompt. Then "q" to quit.

Comment: well, that's quite nifty, but what I'm trying to do here man, is make this call up those 14 variables and add them to the calculations in order to offset the results.

Comment: @lolkuro - What is your coding background and experience? I ask because I'd like to recommend you using a "Strategy Pattern" in your design to allow for a more dynamic functionality (you could add/remove elements etc.) but might be too complicated if you're only using this tool as a simple assistant.

Comment: Give me an example of how you want to use a few of the variables.

Comment: @Capn: I'm a complete newbie to Java. my only coding experience is with an internal system in the SNES Game: Earthbound via ROMHacking. I'm using jGrasp as an editor.

Comment: @Ryan: example:
yourHP = yearBorn * logHPCalc; <- I want to make the element variable affect this, as this is the main calculation for statistical data.
Example 2: yourHP = yearBorn * logHPCalc + [selection of 1 to 5 elements here each with separate "+ elemVariable's"]

Comment: Updated the code in my answer. Run again and answer "fire" and/or "water", but be sure not to answer something that doesn't exist. It's light on error handling.

Comment: please look at my original post for an additional comment since it would take too much space.

Comment: Changed the code sample again. Now all the element stuff is in a single method. If you call it from your code, it will make the user enter from one to five elements, making sure they enter only ones you've defined, and return the values to you so you can do whatever with them.